# Folder upload broken in Opera

Tags: google-chrome, cross-browser, opera

I'm working on a project where user can upload a folder on the web application. The frontend is supposed to read all the files in the folder and process them accordingly.

Input tag used for folder upload:

```
<input type="file" multiple directory webkitdirectory mozdirectory >
```

This functionality of folder upload works as expected in Chrome & FireFox. But this doesn't work in Opera GX. When uploading the folder it only reads one file, instead of reading all the files in the folder as other browsers do.

Created [Github pages](https://vabs.github.io/opera-folder-upload-test/) to verify functionality.

Has anyone found a way around this problem.